# PHP Switch Statement and Array Key Values

Tags: php, curl, switch-statement, translation, days

I am trying to build a small weather forecast on a multilingual website.  I am using PHP curl, and the API is in English.

I am having trouble translating the days of the week.

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'language' => ''
), $atts );

/**
 * Get translated string for given key
 */
function get_translated_text( $key='' ){


    $language = $atts['language'];  // de, fr, it

    switch ( $language ) {

        case 'fr':
            $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'Dim',
                'Mon'   => 'Lun',
                'Tue'   => 'Mar',
                'Wed'   => 'Mer',
                'Thu'   => 'Jeu',
                'Fri'   => 'Ven',
                'Sat'   => 'Sam',
                'Today' => 'Auj',
            );
            break;

        case 'de':
             $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'So',
                'Mon'   => 'Mo',
                'Tue'   => 'Di',
                'Wed'   => 'Mi',
                'Thu'   => 'Do',
                'Fri'   => 'Fr',
                'Sat'   => 'Sa',
                'Today' => 'Heute',
            );
            break;

        default :
               $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'Dom',
                'Mon'   => 'Lun',
                'Tue'   => 'Mar',
                'Wed'   => 'Mer',
                'Thu'   => 'Gio',
                'Fri'   => 'Ven',
                'Sat'   => 'Sab',
                'Today' => 'Oggi',
            );
            break;

    }

    $output = '';

    if ( ! empty( $key ) && isset( $arr[ $key ] ) ) {
        $output = $arr[ $key ];
    }

    return $output;

}
```

This is what I am using the get the week day:

```
<div class="day">
<?php 
$dw = date("D", strtotime($day['date'])); 
echo get_translated_text( $dw ); 
?>
</div>
```

As is, get_translated_text() always returns default value of the switch statement (Italian).

How can we adjust the above function to return key values based on the value of $language?

Hope, I explained myself correctly!   Any input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where this **$language = $atts['language'];** comes from?

Comment: You're not passing `$atts` to your function. This should actually give you an "Undefined variable" error. Do you have error reporting on? If not, turn it on and always check the logs in case things behave strangely.

Comment: $atts['language']  is from WordPress, shortcode attribute :)

Comment: Sure, but it's not a global variable, so you still need to pass it to your function.

Comment: I think you are not getting $atts['language']; try by using a static $language = 'de';

Comment: To avoid this you could use `setlocale` and `strftime` builtin functions

Comment: You may benefit from looking into the [I18n that Wordpress has](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) because your current approach could get out of hand when/if you add more than a few languages.

Comment: @RohitAilani you are right, using static $language = 'de' works ...   So I am not getting a value form $atts['language']

Comment: @MateiMihai for the win!

Comment: ok please mark my comment as helpful in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your comments.

As mentioned the in the comments, the problem was with the $atts variable.

The updated function:

```
/*
**  Shortcode Arguments  
*/
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'language' => ''
), $atts );



/**
 * Get translated string for given key
 */
function get_translated_text( $key='' , $lang ){


    switch ( $lang ) {

        case 'fr':
            $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'Dim',
                'Mon'   => 'Lun',
                'Tue'   => 'Mar',
                'Wed'   => 'Mer',
                'Thu'   => 'Jeu',
                'Fri'   => 'Ven',
                'Sat'   => 'Sam',
                'Today' => 'Auj',
            );
            break;

        case 'de':
             $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'So',
                'Mon'   => 'Mo',
                'Tue'   => 'Di',
                'Wed'   => 'Mi',
                'Thu'   => 'Do',
                'Fri'   => 'Fr',
                'Sat'   => 'Sa',
                'Today' => 'Heute',
            );
            break;

        case 'ru':
             $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'Вс',
                'Mon'   => 'Пн',
                'Tue'   => 'Вт',
                'Wed'   => 'Ср',
                'Thu'   => 'Чт',
                'Fri'   => 'Пт',
                'Sat'   => 'Сб',
                'Today' => 'Сегодня',
              );
            break;

        default :
               $arr = array(
                'Sun'   => 'Dom',
                'Mon'   => 'Lun',
                'Tue'   => 'Mar',
                'Wed'   => 'Mer',
                'Thu'   => 'Gio',
                'Fri'   => 'Ven',
                'Sat'   => 'Sab',
                'Today' => 'Oggi',
            );
            break;

    }

    $output = '';

    if ( ! empty( $key ) && isset( $arr[ $key ] ) ) {
        $output = $arr[ $key ];
    }

    return $output;

}
```

Pass $lang as an argument.

```
<div class="day">
<?php 
$lang = $atts['language'];
$dw = date("D", strtotime($day['date'])); 
echo get_translated_text( $dw, $lang ); 
?>
</div>
```